# Control marker infowindow from outside of google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, triggers, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm trying to open a google maps marker's info window when an element outside of the map is clicked. I've seen a couple of similar questions but haven't seen a working answer.
Here is my code:

html:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="names_div"></div>
```

script:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var names_html = "";

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  names_html += " " +  "<a href='javascript:myclick(" + locations.length + ")' class='Names'>" + locations[i][0] + " </a> <br> <br>" ;
  };

  document.getElementById("names_div").innerHTML = names_html;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
        })(marker, i));

  }

  function myclick(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(locations[i], "click");
  }
```

Its the interaction between the "names_html +=..." line and the "function myclick(i) {..." that's causing the problem i think.

Additionally i could only get the html population of the names_div to work with a separate loop to the markers loop. This may also be the issue!

Thanks, help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined`.  There are two issues:

1. `locations[i]` is not a reference to a `google.maps.Marker` object (you can't trigger a `click` event on it and expect it to do anything useful).  You need to keep references to the markers (say in an array called `gmarkers`, then trigger the `click` event on those:

```
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
```

2. `locations.length` never changes.  You need to code the sidebar links as:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  names_html += " " + "<a href='javascript:myclick(" + i + ")' class='Names'>" + locations[i][0] + " </a> <br> <br>";
};
```

[Working example (not based on your code)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27nc05j5/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeControl: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var names_html = "";

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  names_html += " " + "<a href='javascript:myclick(" + i + ")' class='Names'>" + locations[i][0] + " </a> <br> <br>";
};

document.getElementById("names_div").innerHTML = names_html;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var gmarkers = [];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
  gmarkers.push(marker);
}

function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}
#names_div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="names_div"></div>
```